# Is there a way to pass (and use) document node as parameter to XSLTProcessor in Edge and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xslt, microsoft-edge

I am trying to do XSL transformation in Edge and using a document node as xslt parameter(via XSLTProcessor.setParameter).
The transformToFragment returns null in Edge (and Chrome), but works ok in Firefox.

Is there a way to make the code below working (at least in Edge) or is there no support of document-node as a xslt parameter?
Below is a minimal code to present the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/BennyHilarious/nxzLf9g3/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function example() {
                let xsldocp = new DOMParser();
                const xsldoc = xsldocp.parseFromString(`<?xml version='1.0'?>
                <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
                    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <xsl:output method='xml' omit-xml-declaration='yes'/>

                    <!-- Parameters -->
                    <xsl:param name='ntParam'/>
                    <xsl:param name='strSpaces' select='"&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;"'/> <!-- Default to 4 spaces -->

                    <!-- Global variables -->
                    <xsl:variable name='numTransformLevel' select='$ntParam/PARAMETER/@VALUE'/> <!-- does not work in Edge & Chrome -->
                    <!--xsl:variable name='numTransformLevel' select='2'/--><!-- works OK -->

                    <!-- Handles a generic element node. -->
                    <xsl:template match='*'>
                        <div>
                            <b><xsl:value-of select='$numTransformLevel'/></b>
                            <i><xsl:value-of select='//GROOT/@VALUE'/></i>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:template>

                </xsl:stylesheet>
                `,"application/xml");



                let xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

                // use the xsl sheet
                xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsldoc);

                // create xml
                let parser = new DOMParser();
                const docData = parser.parseFromString("<ROOT><GROOT VALUE='IAM'/></ROOT>", "application/xml");
                

                // create param xml and set the parameter
                parser = new DOMParser();
                const docParam = parser.parseFromString("<PARAM><PARAMETER VALUE='5'/></PARAM>", "application/xml");
                xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "ntParam", docParam.documentElement);

                // do the transformation
                var targetElm = document.getElementById("trCont5");
                let resultFrag = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(docData, targetElm.ownerDocument);

                targetElm.appendChild( resultFrag );
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="example();" value="XLSTParam Test"/><!-- Outputs 5IAM -->
        <div id="trCont5"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code attempts to pass an element node, not a document node. But anyway, with Chromium based browser using libxslt under the hood I don't think browser DOM nodes can be passed to XsltProcessor as parameters, somehow the conversion they do for the input node is not done on parameters of type node. Perhaps SaxonJS is a way out, allows you to use XSLT 3 in the browser and it does support DOM node parameters.

Comment: Ok, understood. I will try the saxon-js approach

Comment: Ok, i gave it a go. it works, thank you for that! I am unfortunately in position where i can't use the licensed software. So instead i chose the following solution:

1) Created an empty XML with<DATAPARAM> root node

2) added the original DATA doc under DATAPARAM/DATA node

3) added the parameter node under DATAPARAM/PARAM node

4) changed the XSL to cope with the changed data-structure

5) cleaned the data after the XSLT (specific for my code)


this is not ideal solution, but hey, this is not an ideal world :-)  i still keep the answer by Martin as valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SaxonJS (docs at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html, download at https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml):

```js
            function example() {

                const xslt = `<?xml version='1.0'?>
                <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
                    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <xsl:output method='html'/>

                    <!-- Parameters -->
                    <xsl:param name='ntParam'/>
                    <xsl:param name='strSpaces' select='"&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;"'/> <!-- Default to 4 spaces -->

                    <!-- Global variables -->
                    <xsl:variable name='numTransformLevel' select='$ntParam/PARAMETER/@VALUE'/> <!-- does not work in Edge & Chrome -->
                    <!--xsl:variable name='numTransformLevel' select='2'/--><!-- works OK -->

                    <!-- Handles a generic element node. -->
                    <xsl:template match='*'>
                        <div>
                            <b><xsl:value-of select='$numTransformLevel'/></b>
                            <i><xsl:value-of select='//GROOT/@VALUE'/></i>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:template>

                </xsl:stylesheet>
                `;            

                // create xml
                let parser = new DOMParser();
                const docData = parser.parseFromString("<ROOT><GROOT VALUE='IAM'/></ROOT>", "application/xml");
                

                // create param xml and set the parameter
                const docParam = parser.parseFromString("<PARAM><PARAMETER VALUE='5'/></PARAM>", "application/xml");
                
                // do the transformation
                var targetElm = document.getElementById("trCont5");
                
                let result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
                transform(map { 
                  'source-node' : .,
                  'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
                  'stylesheet-params' : map {
                     QName('', 'ntParam') : $ntParam
                  }
                })?output`,
                docData,
                {
                  'params' : { 
                  ntParam : docParam.documentElement,
                  xslt : xslt 
                  }
                });

                targetElm.appendChild( result );
            }
```

```css
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="example();" value="XLSTParam Test"/><!-- Outputs 5IAM -->
        <div id="trCont5"></div>
    </body>
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/js/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
 
 
 <input type="button" onclick="example();" value="XSLTParam Test"/><!-- Outputs 5IAM -->
        <div id="trCont5"></div>
```

Note that for compactness and self-containedness of the example I used the `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate`method to call the XPath 3.1 `transform` function on the fly to run the provided XSLT. SaxonJS also allows you to run precompiled XSLT with the `SaxonJS.transform` method, for that you need to use either SaxonEE or the Node.js `xslt3` tool (from Saxonica/NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3) to compile the XSLT file to a JSON file.